# Does anyone know how are these 2 plugins called?

Tags: jquery, plugins

How are these called and where can I find nice ones? This is screenshot from Grocery CRUD, but I want to implement something like this for my own admin.

The first plugin is consisted of 2 lists, the right is with all the elements, and by the dragging or pressing on + sign, the items are moved to the left list which is empty.

The second is something like input field for tags and the problem is I couldn't find any that is that good as this.
When you press the field, the list is opening so you can chose with the mouse click. If you star typing some letters, it gives you prediction too. And if there is no available tag, to be able to insert a new one.

[image: Plugins]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The second plugin looks a lot like the jquery plugin [chosen.js](http://harvesthq.github.com/chosen/). Having used this plugin in a number of sites I'd highly recommend it.

Comment: It also looks a bit like http://jqueryui.com/autocomplete/#multiple with some extra css on top.

Comment: That is true, although the style is almost the same as the default style of chosen. Have a look at the link. I guess both would probably suffice for the need.

Comment: Yeah the one you provided looks exactly like the picture he supplied!

Comment: The Chosen plugin is exactly the same as I looked for. Plus I didn't know about the Option group feature that looks that way. It's perfect for what I need, and the Option group feature would be really useful for my project!

Answer (score 1):

First one is the jQuery UI Multiselect (http://www.webresourcesdepot.com/attractive-multiple-select-inputs-with-jquery-ui/)

Comment: Thanks, that's it! That's what I needed. I just don't know why can't i choose both answers as correct answers...

Comment: I have another question I couldn't find answer for, how can I create <optgroup> for this plugin?